# How to receive an XML-formatted website via OAuth in C#

Tags: c#, xml, http, oauth

At our university we have an API which is usable after verifying with OAuth. Via this API you can get information like student's ID, name, schedule, etc.

Everything up to generating an Access token works,but now I struggle on how to receive XML-formatted data using the access token and secret.

The documentation of the university API states that using `[API-url]/oauth/api/user/?format=xml`,
will return the users' username and ID in an XML-format.

The code I'm using to create an HTTP Web Request is:

```
    public void getUserName(string accessToken, string accessSecret)
    {
        oauth["token"]           = accessToken;
        oauth["token_secret"]    = accessSecret;
        var appUrl = "------------/oauth/api/user/?format=xml";
        var authzHeader = oauth.GenerateAuthzHeader(appUrl, "POST");
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(appUrl);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;
        request.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", authzHeader);

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
        {
            try
            {
                if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Problem:" +
                    Environment.NewLine +
                    response.StatusDescription);
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Success: " + response.StatusDescription);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("There was an error: " + e.Message);
            }
       }
    }
```

Is it true that this method merely creates and sends an HTTP header? Meaning that the actual 'body' of the web-response is missing? If so, how can I retreive the information and display the XML-formatted data?

Comment: Are you seeing the `MessageBox` for success? That is the point that you'll want to do something with the response stream, such as loading it in a `XDocument` (or whatever your preferred XML library is)